# Store custom ListView locally from Azure Database

Tags: android, listview, azure, local

I have an **Activity** which displays a custom **ListView** of a class called Comments. Comments have a title, a body and a date and the **ListView** displays all of them. The comments are being stored in an Azure Database through an Azure Mobile Service. So every time the **Activity** is opened I fetch the comments with an **AsyncTask** on the background thread. But this way the comments have to be downloaded every time the user opens the **Activity**. What I want to do is **store the comments locally** so when the user opens the activity there are some comments that appear instantly while I fetch the newest comments and display them when they are ready.
An example would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Walk through this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/offline-support-in-azure-mobile-services-android-sdk/) from Azure Team and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Kinani I will follow it and let you know the outcome when Im done.